# Multiplicative order equalling the Carmichael Function

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

From Carmichael's Theorem, we have that if $\gcd(a,N)=1$, then if $k$ is the smallest natural number such that $a^k\equiv1\mod N$, then $k$ divides $\lambda(N)$.

What I wanted to check was for what N does it hold true that for all $a=2,3,4,...,N-2$ comprime to $N$ is $k=\lambda(N)$?

Any value of $N$ for which there are no numbers in the range $2,3,...,N-2$ that are not coprime to $N$ can be excluded.  In order for any values of $a$ to exist such that $2\leq a\leq N-2$, we must have that $N\geq 4$.  If we consider the cases where $N=4$ and $N=6$ then the only values of $a$ in the range are not comprime to $N$.  We therefore only need consider the cases where $N=5$ or $N\geq7$.

For all $N\geq5$, we have that $\lambda(N)$ is even.  As such, if $N$ is odd, then either the multiplicative order of $2$ is odd (in which case it can't equal $\lambda(N)$) or it is twice the multiplicative order of $4$ (which then could not equal $\lambda(N))$.  We can therefore prove that the only odd $N$ that is a solution to the question is $N=5$, because otherwise we would need the multiplicative orders of both $2$ and $4$ to be equal to $\lambda(N)$.

If $N$ is equal to $2^mx$ for $m\geq4$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\lambda(N)$ is divisible by $2^{m-2}$ (which is at least $4$ for $m\geq4$) but the multiplicative order of $2^{m-1}x-1$ is $2$.  We therefore only need to consider cases where $N$ is divisible by $2$ but not $16$. We find that for $N$ is a power of $2$, the only solution is $N=8$.

Suppose $N\geq p^2+2$ for some odd prime $p\not\mid N$.  Then, either the multiplicative order of $p$ is odd or it is twice the multiplicative order of $p^2$.  In either case, the multiplicative orders of $p$ and $p^2$ can't both be $\lambda(N)$.  We can therefore add a requirement that $N$ must be divisible by all odd primes that are $\leq\sqrt{N-2}$.

Suppose $N$ is divisible by exactly $q$ different odd primes for $q\geq1$.  We can therefore write $N=(2)^{e_0}(p_1)^{e_1}(p_2)^{e_2}(...)(p_q)^{e_q}$.  WLOG, we can state that $p_1<p_2<...<p_q$.  Let $r$ be the smallest prime such that $r\not\mid N$.  Trivially, if $r<p_{q-1}$, then $r^2+2<p_{q-1}p_q<N$, so we can exclude this possibility.  Suppose $p_{q-1}<r<p_q$. Now, because every integer $x\geq4$, $x$ is less than the product of all the primes less than $x$, we can similarly show that $r^2+2<(r+1)^2<N$ if $q\geq2$, and trivially it is true if $e_1\geq2$.
This leaves possibilities of $N=2^{e_0}p$ for $p>3$. Lastly, we consider the case where $r>p_q$.  If $q\geq4$, we can use Bertrand's Postulate to show that $\frac{r^2}{8}<p_{q-1}p_q$ and therefore $r^2+2<30p_{q-1}p_q\leq N$, and if any of $e_0,e_1,e_2,e_3$ are at least $2$, we can also show this to be true for $q=3$ and exclude those cases as well, as well as the case $q=2$ if the sum $e_0+e_1+e_2\geq4$.  We therefore need to consider cases of $N\in\lbrace2^{e_0}3^{e_1},2^{e_0}3^{e_1}5^{e_2},210\rbrace$.

To summarize so far, we have found solutions of $N=5$ and $N=8$.  Any other solutions must be $N\in\lbrace 2p,4p,8p,2^{e_0}3^{e_1},30,60,90,150,210\rbrace$, where $e_i\geq1$ and $p$ is an odd prime other than $3$. We can exclude any of these possibilities if a prime $r\leq\sqrt{N-2}$ does not divide $N$. Using the example of $r=7$ can exclude the possibilities of $60$, $90$, and $150$, using the example of $r=11$ excludes the possibility of $210$, and using the example of $r=3$ rules out the possibilities of $4p$ and $8p$.  We can further refine our possibilities by limiting $p$ to $5$ (so that $2p<\leq3^2+2$) and by limiting the cases of $2^{e_0}3^{e_1}$ to $\lbrace12,18,24\rbrace$ (so that it is less than $5^2+2$).

We are left to check for solutions from the set $\lbrace10,12,18,24,30\rbrace$.  We have $\lambda(N)=2$ for $12$ and $24$, so both must be solutions.  We also have $\lambda(N)=4$ for $10$ and $30$; $10$ is a solution but because $11^2\equiv1\mod30$, $30$ is not a solution.  Lastly, we have that $\lambda(18)=6$, but $7^3\equiv1\mod18$.

Our solution set is therefore $\lbrace5,8,10,12,24\rbrace$.  Running a script I wrote in Python confirms these are the only solutions for $N\leq250$.

My questions:

1. Is my attempted proof valid?
2. To my eyes, my proof is somewhat scattered and clunky, especially the paragraph about $q$ different odd primes.  How could I streamline the proof?
3. Could I have written a more efficient proof by proving that: possible solutions are either 5 or at least 7; other than $5$, $N$ must be even; if $N$ is divisible by $4$, then $\frac{N}{2}\pm1$ are coprime to $N$ and have multiplicative order $2$, which means that the only possible solutions that are multiples of $4$ have $\lambda(N)=2$, which are $8,12,24$; if $p^2\mid N$ for any odd prime $p$, then $\frac{N}{p}+1$ has multiplicative order $2$ and is coprime to $N$, therefore any remaining solutions for $N$ must be square free; if $N$ is divisible by at least two odd primes, it is greater than $3^2+2$ and therefore it must be divisible by $3$; suppose $N$ can be written as $6xp$ where $x$ is a positive integer and $p$ is prime, then whichever of $2xp\pm1$ is coprime to $N$ (which because $N$ is squarefree, exactly one is coprime to $N$ and exactly one is shares a factor of $3$) has multiplicative order 2, however no squarefree numbers of this form have $\lambda(N)=2$, so any remaining solutions have the form $N=2p$, which leaves $N=10$ as the only option remaining for $N-2\geq3^2$

Answer (score 1):

I skimmed your proof and it seems to be valid. But as you said, it's scattered and clunky while also relying on Bertrand's postulate. I'll provide a far easier proof below.

Notice that your condition for $N$ is incredibly restrictive, and we need to find only one pair in the set that have different orders to eliminate a particular $N$. The condition is satisfied by $N=5$ and trivially by all other $N<7$. So, we consider only $N \geq 7$.

**Lemma 1: $\lambda(N)$ is even.**
*Proof:* $-1$ has order $2$ requiring $\lambda(n)$ to be a multiple of $2$.

We hereby represent the order of $a$ $\bmod n$ as $\operatorname{ord}_n(a)$.

**Lemma 2: N cannot be odd.**
*Proof:* $(4,N)=1$ and $4$ is the square of $2$, implying that the $\operatorname{ord}(4)$ is either odd or half of $\operatorname{ord}(2)$. In either case, $\operatorname{ord}(4) \not = \lambda(n)$.

**Lemma 3: $N=2^t \implies N=8$.**
*Proof:* It is easily verified that $\lambda(8)=2$. When $N>8$, $2^{t-1}+1$ has order $2$. However, $3^2=9 \not \equiv 1 \pmod N$ and therefore $\operatorname{ord}(3)>2$.

**Lemma 4: If $N=p^k$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then $x \not \equiv \pm1$ had order greater than $2$.**

*Proof:* Suppose $\operatorname{ord}(x) \leq 2$, then

$$\begin{align} x^2 & \equiv 1 \pmod {p^k} \\ (x-1)(x+1) & \equiv 0 \pmod {p^k} \end{align}$$
If $x \not \equiv \pm1$, then $p$ divides both $x-1$ and $x+1$ and hence also their difference $=2$, leading to a contradiction.

**Lemma 5: If $(m,n)=1$, $\operatorname{ord}_{mn}(a) = \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{ord}_m(a), \operatorname{ord}_n(a))$.**

*Proof:* Let $\operatorname{ord}_m(a)=h$ and $\operatorname{ord}_n(a)=k$ and their LCM be $l$.
By the Chinese Remainder theorem,

$$a^l \equiv 1 \pmod m \text{ and } a^l \equiv 1 \pmod n \iff a^l \equiv 1 \pmod {mn}$$
Since $h \mid l$ and $k \mid l$, the LHS is satisfied and by implication, so is the RHS. The RHS further implies that $\operatorname{ord}_{mn}(a) \mid l$.
Similarly, $\operatorname{ord}_{mn}(a)$ clearly satisfies the RHS and therefore, the LHS too further implying that it is a multiple of both $h$ and $k$, $\implies l \mid \operatorname{ord}_{m,n}(a)$. Hence,
$$\operatorname{ord}_{mn}(a)= l$$

**Theorem: If the numbers coprime to $N$ in the set $S=\{ 2,3,\ldots , N-2\} $ all have the same order modulo $N$, then $N \leq 6$ or $N=8,12,24$.**

*Proof:* The case of prime power $N$ is already taken care of in Lemmas 2 and 3. We can therefore write $N=2^tm$ where $m$ is odd.

Consider $a \equiv 1 \pmod {2^t}$ and $a \equiv -1 \pmod {m}$. Such an $a$ exists by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, is contained in $S$ and has order equal to $2$ by Lemma 5.

Now, if $m>3$, take $a \equiv 1 \pmod {2^t}$ and $a \not \equiv \pm1 \pmod {m}$. This has order greater than $2$ by Lemmas 4 and 5, and is therefore not a valid $N$.
Similarly, if $t>3$, take $a \equiv 3 \pmod {2^t}$ and $a \not \equiv \pm1 \pmod {m}$. This has order greater than $2$ by Lemmas 2 and 5.

The only remaining $N$ greater than $6$ are $8,12$ and $24$ which are all easily verified.